# why the timeout operator that I have in my http request does not throw an error

Tags: rxjs

the timeout that I defined does not throw any error when the duration parameter I defined is greater than 7000 ms. what is strange is that the timeout operator works well in my code from 0 to 7000 ms

pay(billing: Billing): Observable {

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    //  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  }),
  params: new HttpParams()
    .append('timezone', billing.timezone)
    .append('mode', billing.mode)
    .append('responseFailURL', billing.responseFailURL)
    .append('responseSuccessURL', billing.responseSuccessURL)
    .append('hash', billing.hash)
    .append('txndatetime', billing.txndatetime)
    .append('chargetotal', billing.chargetotal.toString())
    .append('storename', billing.storename.toString())
    .append('currency', billing.currency.toString())
};
// Sending required payment infrmations to Authipay host url
return forkJoin(
  of(2), timer(2000).pipe(mergeMap(value => this.getPayementStatus(billing.txndatetime))).pipe( timeout(7500))
).pipe(
  map(
    ([articles, authorOfTheMonth]) => {
      console.log(authorOfTheMonth);
      return authorOfTheMonth;
    }
  )
).subscribe(
      resp => {
          this.router.navigate(['success'], { relativeTo: this.route });
        } else {
          form.setErrors({ paymentFailed: true });
          this.alertify.error(this.translate.instant('error.payment'));
        }
      },
      error => {
        if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
          this.alertify.error(error.message);
        } else {
          this.alertify.error(this.translate.instant('error.payment'));
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: I don't see your subscription callbacks. Can you post the part of the code where you subscribe to this function ?

Comment: this._paymentService.pay(this.billingModel).subscribe(
          resp => {
           console.log(resp)
          error => {
            if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
              this.alertify.error(error.message);
            }
          }
        );

Comment: I do not understand why the timeout operator does not throw anything when it is set to more than 7000 ms

Comment: can you test the code I posted ? It's a minimalist version of your code toisolate & test just timeout behaviour.

Comment: thank you very much, yes it works very well. however, when the simulateResponseTime function returned an observable<never>, the error timeout never throw, how i can do in this case

Comment: That's weird, it's working fine with `NEVER` for me. Try to replace simulateResponseTime with this definition and tell me what you see ? 
`const simulateResponseTime = (timeInMS)=> EMPTY; // in milliseconds `

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about. it does not work this case precisely when the simulateResponseTime function returns EMPTY

Comment: Well it is normal that nothing happens when you emit `Empty`. The point of `EMPTY`is to complete without throwing any error nor a response. The rest of the pipe will be simply ignored. If you want timeout to be applicable, you need to use `NEVER` instead. You can also use `throwError` directly, this error will be directly catched by error callback in the `subscribe` function.

Comment: It works very well thanks to your advice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeout` seems to work as expected to me.

[I wrote a test here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bx9nqn?file=index.ts) where I replaced your `this.getPayementStatus(billing.txndatetime))` function with a :

**simulated response**

```
const simulateResponseTime = (timeInMS)=> timer(timeInMS); // in milliseconds
```

Which will return a response in `delayOfResponse` milliseconds. With this tool we can test what happens when the response takes more time than timeout threshold:

**Simulation parameters**

```js
const timeoutThreshold = 7500; // in ms
const delayOfResponse = 200; //in ms
```

Finally, a minimalist version of

**Your code**

```js
forkJoin(of(2), timer(2000).pipe(
      mergeMap(value => simulateResponseTime(delayOfResponse))
    ).pipe(timeout(timeoutThreshold))
).pipe(
  ...
).subscribe(
      resp => {
          console.log('Success')
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error message :', error.message)
        console.log('Error type :', error.name)
        console.log('Is a TimeoutError :', error.name === 'TimeoutError' )
      }
  );
```

Comment: thank you very much, yes it works very well. however, when the simulateResponseTime function returned an observable<never>, the error timeout never throw, how i can do in this case